# Solving a least squares matrix having constrained the results

Tags: c#, .net, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I have a rectangular matrix thus:

1, 3, 2, 4, n..
4, 2, 1, 5, n..
n..

and a vector thus:
1, 2, 5, 6, 7, n..

I need to solve the least-squares equation for all columns in the matrix, but I want to constrain the results such that all answers are greater than zero.

I've added the Math.NET package and got as far as
`matrix.QR().Solve(...`

Presumably there is some way to iteratively solve this but there doesn't appear to be a way to specify constraints/conditions to the `Solve` method, and I'm not sure what other method(s) I should use.

Partial code added below:

```
//compounds is Dictionary<int, List<double>> 
var xdata = compounds.Values.Select(v => v.ToArray()).ToArray();
var ydata = new DenseVector(someKnownValues.ToArray());
var matrix = DenseMatrix.OfColumns(ydata.Count(), xdata.Count(), xdata);
var factors = matrix.QR().Solve(ydata);
```

Comment: Would you mind adding your code so we can see where you are with solving this on your own?

Comment: @tnw - brief code added; it's difficult to add more because there is a lot of other processing going into gathering the 'compounds' together.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately solving non-negative (or positive) least squares problems is not supported by Math.NET Numerics out of the box.

Some further information and an algorithm: [Non-negative least squares (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares)

Comment: Thanks Christoph - I will investigate some other libraries

Comment: Hi again Christoph, I am just wondering whether I am able to use any of the other solving methods in Math.NET, such as the WeightedRegression?